# JMeter - How to read properties file

Tags: jmeter

My JMeter project is like this.

```
project
    |
     ----> test (folder containing .jmx)
    |
     ----> properties (folder containing .properties files)
```

In the non-gui mode, I can pass .properties file name to the test via commandline - which I know.

But how can I read this property file in GUI mode while debugging? I do not want to place them in the bin folder. Is there any other way? like a config element? Is it easy to write a custom config element to read a property file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I too had a same requirement. It is easy to write a config element.

Refer to this. http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-property-file-reader-a-custom-config-element/

Comment: The link in the accepted answer talks about using a feature of JM that in 4.0 doesn't exist. Dmitri T's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28781079/1788964) below is the current was of doing it.

Comment: It is a custom plugin. You need to download and place it in appropriate location to make it work. refer to the link

Answer (score 15):

The simplest way is passing the property file location to JMeter running in GUI via `-q` command-line argument as:

```
jmeter.bat -q d:\somefolder\somefile.properties
```

Alternative option is using scripting, i.e. you can read arbitrary .properties file via [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) and the following code:

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("d:/somefolder/somefile.properties"));
props.load(is);
is.close();
```

You'll be able to reference properties loaded this way as normal using [__property()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) or [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function.

For more information on scripting in Apache JMeter and a kind of Beanshell cookbook see [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.

Comment: Thanks. I dont want to use commandline. I consider this beanshell as last option. I know about this already. But i did not want to use it as it would appear in the report. +1 for your time and answer.

Comment: Beanshell Pre or PostProcessor **won't appear in the report and elapsed time will not be recorded** unless you're using [Transaction Controller](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) configured to include time of timers and pre/postprocessors into generated parent sample.

Comment: How -q is different from -p?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Add "tag-jmeter-extn-1.1.jat" in ext of your jmeter. Then you can use  Property file Reader easily

My THScript.properties looks like below

TH_Performance_ScriptName=Web.jmx
Performance_TestData=c:/Result/

Accessing Property file values:

${__P(Performance_TestData)}