# Have to set Number of Threads, Ramp up Period and Loop count from an external properties file

Tags: javascript, java, jmeter

Have to set Number of Threads, Ramp up Period and Loop count from an external properties file, this is to change the above variable of different Thread during the execution from a single file. How to do it?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have threads.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778615/jmeter-how-to-read-properties-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can do it as follows:

   - Add the next 3 lines to *user.properties* file (lives under JMeter's "bin" folder)

     ```
     threads=10
     loops=20
     rampup=30
     ```
   - Configure your [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to read the values from JMeter properties using [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function like

     - `${__P(threads,)}`
     - `${__P(loops,)}`
     - `${__P(rampup,)}`

       [image: Thread Group from properties]
2. You cannot change the numbe of threads once Thread Group has been initialized. However it is possible to manipulate "requests per minute" value on the fly using above "properties" approach, [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) and [Beanshell Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server) combination