# Jmeter: Not reading the property from the property location given from command line

Tags: jmeter, property-files

*File: DevEnv.properties*

```
# Development Environment property file
environment.protocol=https
environment.hostname=dev.env.com
environment.port=443
environment.path=api
```

*File: StagingEnv.properties*

```
# Staging Environment property file
environment.protocol=https
environment.hostname=staging.env.com
environment.port=443
environment.path=stagingapi
```

command used **jmeter -g "StagingEnv.properties" - t "Practice11.jmx"**;

*Test Plan Structure*

```
Test Plan
    JSR223 PreProcessor
    HTTP Request Defaults
    Thread Group
        jp@gc - Dummy Sampler
View Results Tree
```

In short value should read from file location provided in command line and when run directly then it must be read the default value.

[JMX file is attached in this link](https://filebin.net/gnk747tteyqluqbk)

Comment: I am not sure, but did you check the path where your file is located? I am sure you have kept it in "bin" directory. Also, does it throw any error?

Comment: @AbhishekAggarwal; both the files are kept under my working directory; and also i am getting any error.

Comment: Try by keeping it in the "bin" folder or give the absolute path. I have not tried myself, but I did search and found something similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778615/jmeter-how-to-read-properties-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try defining the `${__P(variable,defaultVariable)}` in `User Defined Variables` itself and use it with default values or command line arguments. no need for reading it from properties file.

```
protocol    ${__P(protocol,https)}  
hostname    ${__P(hostname,testHostName.com)}
port        ${__P(port,80)}
```

Then command to use it:

```
jmeter -Dprotocol='http' -Dhost='localhost' -n - t "Practice11.jmx";
```

Comment: Thanks for reply; your solution works. Another solution i tried is reading the default value from user defined values and this is also working. But can you please explain in first case why values not reading from the property location given from command line..